# How to write list of list in chunk file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

I have list of list that looks like this:

```
listThing = [['apple','mango','cherry'],
             ['dog','cat','bird'],
             ['rose','jasmine','sunflower']
             ['hospital','house','school']
             ['chair','table','cupboard']
             ['book','pencil','pen']]
```

I want to write that list into files where the number of files is a predetermined value. Then, the number of lists in each file is the division of the number of all lists and number of files. So if:

```
number of file = 3
number of list in each file = number of all lists/number of file = 6/3 = 2
```

The outputs will look like this:

**file1.txt**

```
apple
mango
cherry
dog
cat
bird
```

**file2.txt**

```
rose
jasmine
sunflower
hospital
house
school
```

**file3.txt**

```
chair
table
cupboard
book
pencil
pen
```

This is what I've tried:

```
import math

allList = len(listThing)
numFile = 3
listInFile = math.ceil(allList/numFile)

for i in range(listInFile):
    with open('file'+str(i)+'.txt', 'w') as out:
        for n in range(listInFile):
            # I don't know what should I do next
```

I do not know how to solve this problem. I'm hoping someone can help me to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: What comes in the for loop in place of `...`? What did you try for that part

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh sorry, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import math

listThing = [['apple','mango','cherry'],
             ['dog','cat','bird'],
             ['rose','jasmine','sunflower'],
             ['hospital','house','school'],
             ['chair','table','cupboard'],
             ['book','pencil','pen']]

allList = len(listThing)
numFile = 3
listInFile = int(math.ceil(allList/numFile))
currentFileIndex = None

for e, lt in enumerate(listThing):
    fileIndex = 1 + int(math.floor(e / listInFile))
    if currentFileIndex != fileIndex:
        currentFileIndex = fileIndex
        currentFile = open('file%d.txt' % fileIndex, 'wb')
    for entry in lt:
        currentFile.write(entry.encode('utf8'))
        currentFile.write(b'\n')
```

Comment: why I get error : `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` in line :`currentFile.write(entry)`

Comment: You're using python3. Gimme a second. Done.

Answer (score 2):

```
import math    

list_of_lists = [['apple', 'mango', 'cherry'],
                 ['dog', 'cat', 'bird'],
                 ['rose', 'jasmine', 'sunflower'],
                 ['hospital', 'house', 'school'],
                 ['chair', 'table', 'cupboard'],
                 ['book', 'pencil', 'pen']]

num_files = 3
all_lists = len(list_of_lists)

lists_per_file = math.ceil(all_lists / num_files)

for i in range(1, num_files + 1):
    with open("file{}.txt".format(i), "w") as file:
        lst_idx = (i-1)*lists_per_file
        for lst in list_of_lists[lst_idx:lst_idx+lists_per_file]:
            for word in lst:
                file.write("{}\n".format(word))
```

Comment: Did you just snipe my answer and change a couple of lines ? You shark! Have an updoot